# How to pass value in java from methods to methods

Tags: java, methods

I am new to java, I want to confirm on how to pass the values from methods to another methods/class.
eg.
in `package1`

```
public class class1
public void method1() {
a + a = e
}
```

in `package1` but in different `class file`

```
public class class2
public void method2() {
b + b = f
}
```

in `package2`

```
public void method3() {
c + c = g
}
```

in `package3`

```
public void method4() {
// how can I get or use the value produce from method 1 , 2 and 3? 
(e) + (f) + (g) = d

}
```

note: I am using Eclipse as IDE.

Comment: Do you know how to call a method? Do you know how to `return` a value from a method?

Comment: None of these methods contain valid Java code, and it's not clear how these methods are in any way related to one another.  Is one of them calling another one?  Are they called by a common parent method?  Something else?  Can you provide a real example which demonstrates what you're trying and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: You need to change the return type of the methods from void to int then use *return* to return the values. I suggest doing a tutorial, because this is a very basic level at which to be asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I want to confirm on how to pass the values from methods to another methods/class. ..."*

There is more than one way to accomplish this.

I recommend utilizing *parameters*, and *return* values.
*[Defining Methods (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)*.

```java
class A {
    static int f(int a) {
        return a + a;
    }
}

class B {
    static int f(int b) {
        return b + b;
    }
}

class C {
    static int f(int c) {
        return c + c;
    }
}

class D {
    static int f() {
        return A.f(1) + B.f(2) + C.f(3);
    }
}
```